# Adding javascript to all google-apps-script

Tags: discussion, tags

I started to follow [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) and saw some questions that had minimal tags and namely omitting [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Since the language is javascript based it would seem silly to not have that tag as well correct?

I can't think of a reason to not have the tag there always?

---

I am not suggesting to make superfluous edits. If need be the question will get everything it deserves. Nor I am suggesting that I go and read *every* [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) to make trivial tag edits.

I am new to the language and wanted to confirm that adding [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) as I go along is a good idea.

Comment: Is it JavaScript or just based on it?

Comment: @Deduplicator _Google Apps Script is a scripting language based on JavaScript that lets you do new and cool things with Google Apps like Docs, Sheets, and Forms_ from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Comment: So, tagging it [tag:js] is wrong then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Apps Script runs server-side, but also serves client-side HTML and JavaScript, handles events (both server-side Google events and client-side window and AJAX-like events). As a result, questions do come up that require knowledge on both sides, and often include jQuery or AngularJS aspects.

There are some circumstances where questions tagged [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) should also be tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), but let's not do any wholesale double-tagging. It's not silly to have just [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), in many cases its appropriate and sufficient to have just that single tag.

The [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag should be present if:

- The problem does not directly involve Google's APIs or Google Apps Script services. Examples might be array or string manipulation questions.
- The problem involves client-side JavaScript, served via HtmlService. In this cases, [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) or [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) may also be appropriate, depending on the question.