# Google-Apps-Script deserves proper syntax-highlighting

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

Currently, there's no syntax-highlighting-hint for [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), [which leads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309272/adding-javascript-to-all-google-apps-script) to a sizable number of those posts being tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) despite that not being all that useful:
While it is JavaScript-based, a JS developer has little if any interest in it, nor most of the time any of the neccessary expertise, as the provided API is completely different.

While there is a good reason JS only got a *default*-hint (too much HTML and CSS), *lang-js* is a better hint for this.

Comment: The question to which you link says nothing about adding the [tag:javascript] tag for reasons of syntax highlighting.

Comment: A lot of [tag:google-apps-script] get tagged with [tag:javascript] because it really *is* javascript (or at least a homebrewed flavor of it). The apps-script tag is lacking in experts, and adding the javascript tag is a way to give them some visibility to people who may be able to answer the questions. Particularly if the question is about syntax, not the api itself. Also, these can always be edited with a proper html comment to fix the syntax highlighting without the javascript tag anyway.