# When should [web-applications] be used on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

[web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) currently has >20k questions but its tag excerpt / wiki doesn't include usage guidelines.

On the other hand, on the *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site, the sister site about **using** web applications, daily gets questions about developing, installing, managing or even about the programming languages, APIs, frameworks and technologies behind a web application that are off-topic on that site. To help people to find a place for a question we have *[Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-developing-web-applications)* (disclaimer, I'm posted this self answered question, and [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) is mentioned there).

Nowadays I think that [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) (the tag on Stack Overflow) is a meta tag and other tags might be better. I.e., questions about developing web applications by using [Google Apps Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script) should instead use  [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application)<sup>1</sup> (usually together with [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). Maybe this tag could have a better excerpt/wiki.

Assuming that it's ok to have [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) on Stack Overflow, when should it be used? What are the most prominent related tags that could be helpful to mention in the wiki?

NOTES:

1. Currently there are [some discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398344/improving-google-apps-script-tags-tag-wikis-and-excerpts) about renaming / better use of tags on questions about Google Apps Script. Maybe the best tag for Google Apps Script web application will be another tag soon, but at this time [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) is the one that we already have.

   UPDATES

   - [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) was made a synonym of [gas-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas-web-app).
   - The above synonym direction was reverted.

---

Related tags:

Web application / web app

- [single-page-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-page-application) 4,607 questions
- [progressive-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive-web-apps) 3,724 questions
- [tizen-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tizen-web-app) 414 questions
- [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) 437 questions
- [web-application-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-application-design) 74 questions
- [offline-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/offline-web-app) 13 questions
- [webapplicationstresstool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webapplicationstresstool) 17 questions
- [web-application-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-application-security) 5 questions

Site / website

- [azure-web-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-sites) 6095 questions
- [static-site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-site) 407 questions

From the sidebar of [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications)

[image: most frequently used related tags]

Comment: I always find it ultra-specific tags like [google-apps-script-web-application] difficult. Why not just use [google-apps-script] in combination with [web-applications]? Otherwise, you can start arguing for [google-apps-script-web-application-in-chrome-developed-on-windows-with-jetbrains-webstorm-hosted-on-centos-8-with-nginx-reverse-proxy]

Comment: What about if before criticizing / "defending" other tags first we talk about [tag:web-applications] and if possible write a good usage guidelines for it? At the end it's possible that we could use these usage guidelines to learn if the other tags are or not helpful.

Comment: @leonheess we also need a [works-on-my-machine-but-not-in-production] tag.

Comment: What do you mean by *"will be other soon"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I tried to improve the wording of the note and also I added an update.

Answer (score 3):

A very long time ago, writing an complete application using Javascript that loaded as a single web page was novel and uncommon enough to have its own tag. At the time, most Javascript frameworks were used to make small parts of static Web pages respond in real time; e.g., to enable a Login button when the password is typed.

I think a historical lock on the tag would be useful. As I can't think of any use for it these days.   I expect no one is a true expert in the tag, and few people use it to filter questions anymore.

Comment: Did you mean "a historical lock on the *tab*", or "on the *tag*"? Either way, there is no facility for doing so. Historical locks apply only to individual questions. And while tags could, in the past, be blacklisted, that is no longer an option available to us.

Comment: Before the @CodyGray comment I searched about "historical lock on the tag" (: Some related findings [Tags can be locked to prevent their usage. Should we lock the DO NOT USE tags which are too large for current burnination efforts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385685/1595451), (from 2019) [Locking bad tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280215/1595451) (from 2014)

Comment: I think that might be a good idea to include something like the first paragraph on the [tag:web-applications] wiki.

Comment: @Rubén - assuming anyone reads it ;) But something like this can indeed help as a notice on the excerpt (not fool-proof, but better than nothing currently)

Comment: @CodyGray  why isn't tag blacklist available? Isn't the tooling there?

Comment: @Braiam Shog9 was the only one who maintained it, and he no longer works here. We don't have CMs with developer access anymore, so there's no one who can maintain the blacklist. Also, the developers are now saying that the blacklist causes performance problems. I think that's specious, but it isn't up to me...

Answer (score -4):

**Update**:

- [azure-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-apps) deemed unnecesary and merged to [azure-web-sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-web-sites)
- [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) => [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) consensus reached(6 against 1) <strike>and moderator intervention request is pending.</strike> Synonymized [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

**Usage guideline:**

The tag [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) can be used as a generic tag where more specific tags aren't applicable, available, or feasible.

Given that there's a need for a tag in almost all languages + their web-app communication, It isn't feasible or prudent to create a combined tag for every language or platform. For eg, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) uses the [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) tag [in combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+web-applications) and [java-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-web-app) is NOT created.

Having said that, it should be used as a tag of exclusion, where there isn't a specific tag available/applicable. On that note, I agree with @IanRingrose. Usage with [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) or [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask) is redundant at this point.

---

**Google apps script web application:**

Since the question focuses on [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application)(hereafter, just gas-web-app), I'll explain the issue with this combined tag in this section. I'm qualified to speak on the subject as a gold badge holder in the parent tag [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) and the third top answerer in the [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) tag and the original creator of the tag.

- *What is a Google Apps Script Web Application?* It isn't anything special. It's just a basic web app with [server side is written in Apps Script (instead of, say, [tag:php]) and with plain old HTML + JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) on the client-side with free Google hosting.
- **Adding a prefix to a tag won't change the fact that it is a meta tag or magically make a meta tag specific enough.** If [beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner) is a meta tag, so is [google-apps-script-beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-beginner). If [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) is a meta tag, [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) is also a meta tag. What makes [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) a broad tag? If I have to guess, the availability of JavaScript libraries like [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) or [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs). As the client-side in gas-web-app is just plain JavaScript,  all the same libraries are available here.
- Given that neither [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) nor [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) is specific enough in most cases, it's preferable to

  - Synonymize sub tag [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) => parent tag [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)
  - Use appropriate tags according to the issue at hand(preferably with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)): [cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [same-origin-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/same-origin-policy),[x-frame-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x-frame-options),[iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iframe) are all relevant and can be dynamically used on questions instead of a single useless tag.
  - This strategy is also mentioned by [@Mogsdad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) in this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309373/)