# Synonymize sub-tag [google-apps-script-web-application] to main tag [google-apps-script]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request, synonym-removal-request

**Why?**

- Subject matter experts participating in meta agree that a separate tag isn't warranted and should be synonymized: [Current Consensus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219659/vote-google-apps-script-web-applicationgoogle-apps-script):

  - For: ★NEW★7(4 Gold badge holders+3 bronze badge holders)(15pts).

    - Special mention: **@Mogsdad**(*The first Apps script gold badge owner*)
    - @Tanaike
    - @Alan Wells
    - @TheMaster
    - @Oleg Valter
    - @Rafa Guillermo
    - @Ziganotschka
  - Against: 1 Silver badge holder(2pts)

    - @Ruben
- More than 80% of the questions in the tag were a result of retagging. 54% me. The  rest 26% by other 4 users - [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1274673/1570416/percent-of-users-who-added-this-tag)
- 4 out of the top 5 users who added this tag want to synonymize this tag.
- Users asking about web-apps don't generally use this tag. The [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) has 400 questions. But questions about web-app tagged with **only** [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)(without [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application)) are 4 times that(1700)- [SEARCH](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgoogle-apps-script%5d-%5bgoogle-apps-script-web-application%5d%20doGet*%20is%3aq)(They almost always contain `doGet`)
- Almost ALL questions about web-apps can be handled by apps script experts. 88% of the above 1700 has a answer. If there's a specific issue, supplementary tags like [cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors),[html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) provides dynamic relevant tags
- Most bulk question editing annoys general users of the tag.
- [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) is 34 characters. Enough said.

**So, why not create a synonym claim?**

- In the initial stages of our consolidation  project, We were not aware that tags cannot be chained. We synonymized [google-apps-script-html-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-html-service) and [gas-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas-web-app) to [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application). Now, We can't create this subtag as a synonym of the main tag. It says

> Failed to propose synonym:

> Reverse synonym google-apps-script-web-application already proposed on the tag gas-web-app

**So we need moderator intervention!**

Comment: The tag needs to go. There is too much branching of `google-apps-script-*`, lots of inconsistent naming and multiple tags which are either duplicates or encapsulated by other tags. +1 for having this synonymised. -1 for creating the tag, +1 for humility ;)

Comment: Related [When should \[web-applications\] be used on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399422/1595451)

Comment: Not related. Tag [tag:web-applications] has nothing to do with the current request.

Comment: actually it does because [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] has two parents :)

Comment: Irrelevant. The request is only about 1 parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by [JonClements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements).

Given the overwhelming majority vote(unanimous, if not for one user), the following actions are done:

- Synonym link [gas-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas-web-app) and [google-apps-script-html-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-html-service) removed from [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application)
- All three tags [gas-web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas-web-app), [google-apps-script-html-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-html-service), [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) synonymized to main parent [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).
- Users willing to ask questions about web apps can tag more specific tags like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors) as suggested by @Mogsdad  [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309373/)

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem at all of having [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) as ab "independent" tag as almost all questions that have this tag also have [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). This is actually the contrary of what was happening with other requests where some users disagree about certain tag i.e [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) where many of the questions having it, haven't [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) + [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

Also this case differ from other synonym requests as these tags doesn't means the same.

Now [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) not only is used for questions about the Google Apps Ssript simple triggers `doGet` / `doPost`, it's also used for questions about creating custom dialogs and sidebars for G Suite editors (Google Sheets, Docs, etc.) which don't use those triggers

Also, the number of questions that use this tag should not be compared with the number of questions having [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) because it is several years older than [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application)

[google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) should not be synomized to [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) because the scope of the first is very narrow compared to the scope of the later.

For those that are not familiar with [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) it's a platform that include several web apps like the "Developer Hub" the Script Editor, it uses Google Cloud Projects to  handle several settings and features like the OAuth consent screen.

Similar tags to [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application) regarding they have a narrow scope are [gsuite-addons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite-addons), [google-apps-script-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-addon), among others. It make sense to have all of them because they have specific publishing process as well their respective oddities.

Comment: It seems you have all dug yourself a pretty deep hole where the only ones who'd be able to know how to use this multitude of tags is a handful of regulars. Simplicity is good, this entire system of tags seem to be the opposite.

Comment: @ivarni - actually, what we are trying to do now is to clean up what was done before the project (mostly), hence the excessive discussion... Currently, most tags are synonymized or merged to the main tag, and only a few remnants remain. The platform is also notoriously bad at classifying products and services, so everything is indeed kind of a mess. We are trying to reconcile everything, though